# How to using a struct defined in the c header for fortran?

Tags: c, fortran, header-files, fortran-iso-c-binding, language-interoperability

I have a *.H that define a struct. Like this:

```
#define nfloats 9999
#define nword   655

typedef struct {

int a
short b
unsigned short d
float e
char t[nword]
short un[14]
float  dat[nfloats];

} datafile
```

In a void c all parameters of datafile is assigned a value. I want to pass the assigned values to main fortran program without having to redefine using TYPE. Just calling *.H and iso_c_binding. In other words, I wish use "datafile" in fortran main program that was already defined in *. H. Someone suggests something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, you can do it but it needs to translate c types to fortran, so you need a translator or interpreter.

Comment: The Fortran ISO C Binding doesn't understand C inside of the Fortran source code.  It gives you ways of specifying in Fortran to use variables,   calls, etc. that are compatible with C. You have to write that Fortran code; its not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write a script in your favourite language that reads the C definition and converts it to Fortran.  If you fix your syntax then it is quite easy.

1) #define xxx yyy becomes integer, parameter:: xxx = yyy

2) There is no unsigned in Fortran so unsigned shorts and shorts are both integer(kind=1).

3) It depends on how you are using the character arrays.  If they are returning individual characters, not assigned en block, then they can be declared as character t(nword).  If they are expected to hold strings then they should be declared character(len=nword) t.

4) typedef struct {
...
} datafile

becomes

type datafile
   sequence
   ...
end type

5) Having done all that, you need to make sure that both the C and Fortran code have the same byte alignment.  Your char array of 655 is not on a byte boundary so you might get alignment problems.

A second method is to play with macros and get the macros to do the generation for you.  You need to define one set of macros for C and another set for Fortran.  So you'd get something like

```
STRUCT_BEG(datafile)
   INTEGER(a)
   SHORT(b)
   ...
   CHARA(t,nword)
   FLOATA(dat,nfloats)
STRUCTEND(datafile)
```

The C defines would be

```
#define STRUCT_BEG(ignore) typedef struct {
#define STRUCT_END(name)   } name;
#define INTEGER(a) int a;
#define CHARA(a,length) char a[length];
```

The Fortran defines would be something like

```
#define STRUCT_BEG(name) \
    type name \
        sequence
#define STRUCT_END(ignore) end type
#define INTEGER(a) integer::a
#define CHARA(a,length) character(len=length):: a
```

If you compile with -e, the C compiler can be used to generate both headers.